# Is it possible to cancel a tag synonym suggestion?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I cannot find any information about this in Meta: Is it possible to cancel a tag synonym suggestion?

It seems that it is not, but just to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not. You can advocate people who can vote to vote it down, though. It only takes a -2 score on the suggestion for it to be automatically rejected.

Comment: And is it valid to advocate publicly for a vote up/down? (btw: I did not downvote your answer)

Comment: For a synonym suggestion? There's certainly nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @animuson but, maybe, just maybe, is there any chance that SE team will add possibility to cancel my own suggestion?